# Creating an empty instance of a class

Tags: c++, class, parameters, constructor, string

Ok, I have a class `Set` who keeps a `vector<int>` as its data payload. It has a constructor that accepts a `string` as a parameter such as `Set test = Set("1 2 3 4 5 6");` I have a function that reads the line, and parses it into a `vector<int>` from there I can perform operations on the `Set`. The problem comes when `Set test = Set("");` is called, my constructor cannot make a `Set` because it has nothing to parse. My program can't go anywhere. I've tried putting if else statements in the constructor but how can I declare an empty `set`?

Right now I get a segmentation fault.

```
#include "Set.h"

using namespace std;

/***************************************************************************************
 * Constructors and Destructors
**/
Set::Set(){
}
Set::Set(string inputString) {
    if(inputString != ""){
        readLine(inputString);
    }
    else{
        //I've tried several things here, none of which work.
    }
}


Set::~Set(){
}

/***************************************************************************************
 * readLine function
 * 
 * This function takes in a string, takes the next int, and stores in in a vector.
 *
 * Parameters: string, the string to be parsed.
 * 
**/
void Set::readLine(string inString){
        ScanLine scanLine;
        scanLine.openString(inString);
        while(scanLine.hasMoreData()){
            addToSet(scanLine.nextInt());
        }
}

/***************************************************************************************
 * addToSet function
 * 
 * This function takes in a int that is an element and adds it to "this" Set.
 *
 * Parameters: int, the element to be added.
 * Return: int, the value that was added.
 * 
**/
int Set::addToSet(int element){
    int returnValue = -1;
    if(!containsElement(element)){
        this->theSet.push_back(element);
        returnValue = element;
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted? What makes you believe that you need to replace `//I've tried several things here, none of which work.` with anything?

Comment: If I leave off the else statement, I get segmentation fault 11. Which made me think I needed an else.

Comment: The code you posted is not responsible for the segmentation fault. Provide a [short, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org).

Comment: What is the most probable cause for a segmentation fault 11?

Comment: Accessing memory that does not belong to your application. Most frequently this happens when dereferencing uninitialized pointers or reading or writing beyond array boundaries.

Comment: This problem is confusing me because if I take out the if statement testing for a blank string, it works fine. But the requirement is that it must be able to recognize and initialize an empty set. I must be looking in the wrong places.

Comment: What do you mean by "tried several things"? I don't see the problem of leaving the code as you posted it. If you want to know if the set is empty after calling the constructor you can just call `size()` and see if it's 0.

Comment: I don't see the problem either, but I don't want to know whether it is empty, I just want to be able to add an empty set, to a vector of sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. In my equals function, I had `if(!set1.size() == set2.size())` when I should have had `if(set1.size() != set2.size())`, for some reason that was causing a segmentation fault.